# How to create a ImageView when user Scroll to down of layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, scrollview

I have a long `ScrollView` in my layout.
What I want, is that when the user scrolls to the bottom of the Layout(not physical Screen), an `ImageView` to appear in the bottom of the layout so I can click on it.
How can i create this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here I have some code I use to load a large scrollview page by page. When you scroll to the last items of list, the scroll listener fires a http call to get the next page.

```
lv_wall.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener()
{

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
        {
            if (first)
            {
                first = false;
            }
            else
            {
                boolean lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && lv_wall.getChildAt(visibleItemCount - 1) != null
                        && lv_wall.getChildAt(visibleItemCount - 1).getBottom() <= lv_wall.getHeight();

                if (!blocked && lastItem && more_pages)
                {
                    ++page;
                    getWall();
                }
            }
        }
});
```

Instead of `++page` and `getWall()` you can make your `ImageView` appear.

Comment: I do not have a list. I have a just long ScrollView with many elements on it. I want when user Scroll to down of layout, an imageview appear.

Comment: Iook at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713312/can-i-have-onscrolllistener-for-a-scrollview