# handling scrolling in android scrollview

Tags: android, android-scrollview, floating-action-button

I am using [this library](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) to create a floating action button in my android application. What I need is to hide the floating action button when I scroll down, and show it again when I scroll up. The problem is I have a `FrameLayout` and a `ScrollView` that doesn't contain a `setOnScrollListener()`!

I read [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713312/can-i-have-onscrolllistener-for-a-scrollview), but supposedly it is laggy.

Can anyone tell me how to reach get the functionality I'm looking for without losing performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Try this library.**](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton)

It provides a floating action button that disappears when you scroll down :-)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create an ObservableScrollView that has a scroll listener.  Google uses this approach in the IOSched14 app.  One way of creating this might be:

```
public class ObservableScrollView extends ScrollView {
    private boolean mScrollingEnabled = true;
    private ArrayList<Callbacks> mCallbacks = new ArrayList<Callbacks>();

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        for (Callbacks c : mCallbacks) {
            c.onScrollChanged(l - oldl, t - oldt);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int computeVerticalScrollRange() {
        return super.computeVerticalScrollRange();
    }

    public void addCallbacks(Callbacks listener) {
        if (!mCallbacks.contains(listener)) {
            mCallbacks.add(listener);
        }
    }

    public static interface Callbacks {
        public void onScrollChanged(int deltaX, int deltaY);
    }



    public void setScrollingEnabled(boolean scrollingEnabled) {
        mScrollingEnabled = scrollingEnabled;
    }

//    @Override
//    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
//        if (!mScrollingEnabled) return false;
//        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
//    }

}
```

Simply add this instead of your ScrollView and then attach a listener using the addCallbacks method:

```
ObservableScrollView scrollView = new ObservableScrollView(context);
scrollView.addCallbacks(this);
```