# how to manage onTouchListener and onClick at a time

Tags: android, onclick, gesture, ontouchlistener

I want to detect gesture on my ScrollView and its childs . I wanna have all those onClick method working as well.  Say there is a button surrounded with LinearLayout and the whole thing is surrounded with ScrollView .  I wanna call an action when user swipe anywhere of the ScrollView..
I applied onTouchListener to ScrollView.. But as the LinearLayout is clickable, event isn't fired when I  swipe over the linear layout. 
and if I set touch listener to all those child view, then onclick doesn't work.

remebmer using facebook lite ? user reads, scrolls news feed  taps "like" button. clicks on links.. But still it can show chat list when user swipes from right to left on any part of screen..  how do they do it ?

Comment: implement " dispatchTouchEvent " in your views is a possible solution

Comment: yess yess yess..  it worked like a charm .  thanks @VoidExplorer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `onTouchListener` to do this job for you. Use `onScrollChangedListener`. See this answer for more info [Can I have onScrollListener for a ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713312/can-i-have-onscrolllistener-for-a-scrollview). This question has been answered many times all over internet.