# Start animation if view is in focus

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a android app and with several Textviews inside linear layyout which is inside scrollview. On a button click I can bring focus and animate any textView (like move left to right). But What I want is, On Scrolling, if a TextView has Focus, animation for this textView should start. Just like this [website](http://52.36.146.3/solar/).
I have an idea, which is: If scroll changes, check textview.hasFocus(), if true then startAnimation. But I don't know which method to use for checking 'if page scrolled'? I don't even know if this is right approach? Please help.

Comment: did you tried implementing OnScrollChangedListener  ?

Comment: @SaeedJassani, well thank you for guiding in right direction. I implemented [this answer at other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23365539/4410104) and guess what it works.

Comment: Glad that it worked