# How can I add a listener on android scroll view? C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, scroll, scrollview

I'm currently developing for Android using C# and Xamarin.

I want to add a listener to the scroll views that I have within my app, so that it picks up when a user is touching the scroll bar.

How can I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- [Refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713312/can-i-have-onscrolllistener-for-a-scrollview) , in xamarin.android usage like this

  ```
  public class MainActivity : Activity, IOnScrollChangedListener
  {
  ScrollView msv;

  public void OnScrollChanged()
  {
      float scrollY = msv.ScrollX;
      float scrollX = msv.ScrollY;
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("x:=" + scrollY + "  y=" + scrollX );
      //do something
  }

  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
      base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

      // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
      SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
      msv = FindViewById<ScrollView>(Resource.Id.sv);
      msv.ViewTreeObserver.AddOnScrollChangedListener(this);

  }
  }
  ```
- you can also write up a class `MyScrollView` to extend `ScrollView`,and then *override* `OnTouchEvent` or `onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldX, int oldY)`method to implement your function.

Comment: Thanks very much! I managed to get this working. However, I am using analytics to track all events within my app, so in this case I will track when the scroll is clicked. I have just tested it and the count for the scroll bar is +115, can you help with this? 

Thanks again!

Comment: You mean you are using `Google Analytics` to track events , and you want to track the click event of the `ScrollView` not scroll event?

Comment: I want to check when the user has tapped on a scroll bar - I hope this makes sense :)