# How to hide a view if scroll view is at top?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

How can I detect if a scroll view is scrolled to the top? I would like to hide a view if the scroll view is not scrolled to the top and show if it is. I am coding this in kotlin.

Comment: It's sound a bit like a reason to use Coordinator Layout:
https://medium.com/martinomburajr/android-design-coordinator-layout-1-an-introduction-10a1b91ded28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are many ways to get scroll position,

```
scrollView.viewTreeObserver.addOnScrollChangedListener {
    if (scrollView.scrollY <= 0) {
        // scroll top
    } else {
        // other
    }
}
```

requires API level 23

```
scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener { _, _, scrollY, _, _ ->
    if (scrollY <= 0) {
        // scroll top
    } else {
        // other
    }
}
```

[Can I have onScrollListener for a ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713312/can-i-have-onscrolllistener-for-a-scrollview)

this link will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(OnScrollChangedListener {
                val scrollY = rootScrollView.getScrollY() 
                val scrollX = rootScrollView.getScrollX() // Use this coordinate to know where you are

})
```